# Refresh list on vue-native with NativeBase

Tags: react-native, native-base, vue-native

I can't seem to figure out how to refresh a list by pulling it down on vue-native with NativeBase. I know it's possible on react-native but I can't find any information on how to make it work with vue-native. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you ask for (an example?) But I think you can always use the 'RefreshControl' component of react-native: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/refreshcontrol

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this:

import in `<scripts>`:

```
import { RefreshControl } from 'react-native';
```

in methods add a function to refresh some list:

```
_onRefresh(){
     this.refreshing = true
     this.getPictures()
     this.refreshing = false
},
```

In data:

```
data() {
    return {
        refreshing: false
    }
},
```

In your `<template>` above your `<nb-list>` from NativeBase add:

```
<RefreshControl
    :refreshing="refreshing"
    :onRefresh="_onRefresh"
/>
```